# Redux form - show label only when input clicked

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am new to using redux-form. I have a render field with various meta data.

```
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) =>
  <div className='field'>
    <label>
      {label}
      {touched &&
        ((
          error &&
            <span>
               : {error}
            </span>) ||
          (
            warning &&
              <span>
                 : {warning}
              </span>
        ))}
    </label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to refactor this - so the label only shows - once the user has clicked on the input.

would it be something like this?

```
{touched &&
  <label>
    {label}
    {touched &&
      ((
        error &&
          <span>
             : {error}
          </span>) ||
        (
          warning &&
            <span>
               : {warning}
            </span>
      ))}
   </label>
}
```

---

Comment: And what is your problem if you try your approach ?

Comment: ok I managed to get it working -- if I wrap {label}  -- {touched && <span>{label}</span>}  -- but then the fields jump when it comes into existence

Comment: Made the label - a display: block; height: 25px; - that's fixed the jumping

Comment: Great that you solved yourself :)

Comment: Yeah - I wasn't sure - if there was something like onclick - instead of touched.

Comment: Please add an actual answer rather than editing the answer into the question. You're free and encouraged to self-answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

solved final code. I managed to get it working by wrapping the label variable in its own touched event.

```
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) =>
  <div className='field'>
    <label>
      {touched &&
        <span>
          {label}
        </span>
      }
      {touched &&
        ((
          error &&
            <span className="error">
              : {error}
            </span>) ||
          (
          warning &&
            <span className="warning">
              : {warning}
            </span>
        ))}
    </label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
label{
  display:block;
  height: 24px;
}
```